# C# WPF show element directly on screen

Tags: c#, wpf, image, screen, preview

I know there is a way to show "elements" (in my case an Image) directly on the screen, independent of the App.
I belive you control indirectly the graphical part of your system.
Sometimes you see it if a service starts and it is "hiding" in the background.

I want to show an Image object on the screen for few seconds as a preview.

how does it work?

Comment: I think you are getting confused by the concept of a splash screen, which is definitely part of an application.

Comment: No i don't. I know about splash screen. I don't want it on application start for only one time. I want it on every click on an Image and you will see it on a bigger size directly on the screen.

Comment: Please improve the description of what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Where have you seen this before?

Comment: Why don't you create a window (maybe a borderless one) and show your _preview_ image in that?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Updated code**

> How does it work?

I don't think what your looking for actually exists(a ready and an easy to use preview-something solution) but you can always TRY and find a work-around and if you fail then you can always ask our community of programmers.

My project:

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="previewOrSmthn.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:previewOrSmthn"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgToPreview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MouseDown="imgToPreview_MouseDown"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

Preview.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="previewOrSmthn.Preview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:previewOrSmthn"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Preview" Height="250" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Width="250" ResizeMode="NoResize"  WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgPreview" Margin="0"/>

</Grid></Window>
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string Path = "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg";
    Preview prevwnd = new Preview();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imgToPreview.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path));
        prevwnd = new Preview(Path);         
    }
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

   private void imgToPreview_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            prevwnd.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Preview.Xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class Preview : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer ThreeSec = new DispatcherTimer();
    public Preview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Preview(string imgSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imgPreview.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgSource));
        imgPreview.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        ThreeSec.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        ThreeSec.Tick += ThreeSec_Tick;
        Loaded += Preview_Loaded;

    }

    private void ThreeSec_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Preview_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreeSec.Start();
    }
}
```

Good luck taking it on from here!(As in making it better like setting owner..etc) I made everything simple to understand. Comment if you have a question.